# How do I achieve the throughput of 50k/sec in inserting my data in Cassandra while reading input from a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cql

My aim is to increase the throughput of versioning data in Cassandra. I have used concurrent reads and writes and have also increased the chunk size that my code reads from the file. My machine is 16gb with 8 cores and yes, I have changed Cassandra's yaml file for 10k concurrent reads and writes and when timed it, I found out that 10000 writes/reads takes less than a second.
My minimal, viable code is:

```
import json
import logging
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from hashlib import sha256, sha512, sha1

import pandas as pd
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel, WriteTimeout
from cassandra.cluster import (EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT, BatchStatement, Cluster,
                               ExecutionProfile)
from cassandra.concurrent import (execute_concurrent,
                                  execute_concurrent_with_args)
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement, dict_factory


class PythonCassandraExample:
    def __init__(self, file_to_be_versioned, working_dir=os.getcwd(), mode='append'):
        self.cluster = None
        self.session = None
        self.keyspace = None
        self.log = None
        self.mode = mode
        self.file_to_be_versioned = file_to_be_versioned
        self.insert_patch = []
        self.delete_patch = []
        self.update_patch = []
        self.working_dir = working_dir

    def __del__(self):
        self.cluster.shutdown()

    def createsession(self):
        profile = ExecutionProfile(
            row_factory=dict_factory,
            request_timeout=6000
        )
        self.cluster = Cluster(
            ['localhost'],
            connect_timeout=50,
            execution_profiles={
                EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT: profile
            }
        )
        self.session = self.cluster.connect(self.keyspace)

    def getsession(self):
        return self.session

    # How about Adding some log info to see what went wrong
    def setlogger(self):
        log = logging.getLogger()
        log.setLevel('INFO')
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"))
        log.addHandler(handler)
        self.log = log
    # Create Keyspace based on Given Name

    def handle_error(self, exception):
        self.log.error("Failed to fetch user info: %s", exception)

    def createkeyspace(self, keyspace):
        """
        :param keyspace:  The Name of Keyspace to be created
        :return:
        """
        # Before we create new lets check if exiting keyspace; we will drop that and create new
        self.log.info("creating keyspace...")
        self.session.execute("""
                CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS %s
                WITH replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1' }
                """ % keyspace)
        self.log.info("setting keyspace...")
        self.keyspace = keyspace
        self.session.set_keyspace(self.keyspace)

    def create_table_and_set_version(self, table_name):
        self.table_name = table_name.lower()
        table_select_query = "SELECT table_name FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name='{}' AND table_name='{}'".format(
            self.keyspace, self.table_name)
        print(table_select_query)
        table_exists = self.session.execute(table_select_query).one()
        self.log.info("Table exists: {}".format(table_exists))
        if table_exists:
            self.log.info(
                "Datapackage already exists! Checking the last version")
            self.version = self.session.execute(
                "SELECT version FROM {} LIMIT 1".format(self.table_name)).one()
            self.log.info(
                "The version fetched is: {} of type: {}".format(
                    self.version, type(self.version)
                )
            )
            if not self.version:
                self.version = 0
            else:
                self.version = self.version['version']
        else:
            self.log.info("Table didn't exist!")
            self.version = 0
        self.target_version = int(str(self.version)) + 1
        self.log.info(
            "Current and candidate versions are: {}, {}".format(
                self.version,
                self.target_version
            )
        )
        # c_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (id varchar, version int, row varchar, row_hash varchar, PRIMARY KEY(id, version)) with clustering order by (version desc)".format(
        #     self.table_name)
        c_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (id varchar, version int, row_hash varchar, PRIMARY KEY(version, id))".format(
            self.table_name
        )
        self.session.execute(c_sql)
        self.log.info("DP Table Created !!!")
        self.log.info("Current and candidate versions are: {}, {}".format(
            self.version, self.target_version))

    def push_to_update_patch(self, update_patch_file, last_patch=False):
        if len(self.update_patch) >= 10000:
            with open(update_patch_file, mode='a') as json_file:
                json_file.writelines(
                    self.update_patch
                )
            del self.update_patch[:]
        if last_patch is True and len(self.update_patch) > 0:
            with open(update_patch_file, mode='a') as json_file:
                json_file.writelines(
                    self.update_patch
                )
            del self.update_patch[:]

    def push_to_insert_patch(self, insert_patch_file, last_patch=False):
        if len(self.insert_patch) >= 10000:
            with open(insert_patch_file, mode='a') as json_file:
                json_file.writelines(
                    self.insert_patch
                )
            del self.insert_patch[:]
        if last_patch is True and len(self.update_patch) > 0:
            with open(insert_patch_file, mode='a') as json_file:
                json_file.writelines(
                    self.insert_patch
                )
            del self.insert_patch[:]

    def push_to_delete_patch(self, delete_patch_file, last_patch=False):
        if len(self.delete_patch) >= 10000:
            with open(delete_patch_file, mode='a') as json_file:
                json_file.writelines(
                    self.delete_patch
                )
            del self.delete_patch[:]
        if last_patch is True and len(self.delete_patch) > 0:
            with open(delete_patch_file, mode='a') as json_file:
                json_file.writelines(
                    self.delete_patch
                )
            del self.delete_patch[:]

    def push_to_patch(self, key, value, mode='update'):
        return
        if key is None or value is None:
            raise ValueError(
                "Key or value or both not specified for making a patch. Exiting now."
            )
        data = {}
        data["id"] = str(key)
        data["data"] = json.dumps(value, default=str)
        # convert dict to json str so that the patch is a list of line jsons.
        data = json.dumps(data, default=str)
        json_patch_file = os.path.join(
            self.working_dir,
            "version_{}_{}.json".format(
                self.target_version, mode
            )
        )
        if mode == 'update':
            self.update_patch.append(
                data + "\n"
            )
            self.push_to_update_patch(
                json_patch_file
            )
        if mode == 'insert':
            self.insert_patch.append(
                data + "\n"
            )
            self.push_to_insert_patch(
                json_patch_file
            )
        if mode == 'delete':
            self.delete_patch.append(
                data + "\n"
            )
            self.push_to_delete_patch(
                json_patch_file
            )

    def clone_version(self):
        if self.mode == 'replace':
            return
        self.log.info("Cloning version")
        start_time = datetime.utcnow()
        if self.version == 0:
            return
        insert_sql = self.session.prepare(
            (
                "INSERT INTO  {} ({}, {}, {}) VALUES (?,?,?)"
            ).format(
                self.table_name, "id", "version", "row_hash"
            )
        )
        futures = []
        current_version_query = "SELECT id, row_hash FROM {} WHERE version={}".format(
            self.table_name, self.version
        )
        current_version_rows = self.session.execute(
            current_version_query
        )
        for current_version_row in current_version_rows:
            params = (
                current_version_row['id'],
                self.target_version,
                current_version_row['row_hash']
            )
            futures.append(
                (
                    insert_sql,
                    params
                )
            )
        self.log.info(
            "Time taken to clone the version is: {}".format(
                datetime.utcnow() - start_time
            )
        )

    def hash_string(self, value):
        return (sha1(str(value).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())

    def hash_row(self, row):
        row_json = json.dumps(row, default=str)
        return (self.hash_string(row_json))

    def insert_data(self, generate_diff=False):
        self.generate_diff = generate_diff
        destination = self.file_to_be_versioned
        chunksize = 100000
        concurrency_value = 1000
        patch_length_for_cql = chunksize
        chunks = pd.read_csv(destination, chunksize=chunksize)
        chunk_counter = 0
        insert_sql = self.session.prepare(
            (
                "INSERT INTO  {} ({}, {}, {}) VALUES (?,?,?)"
            ).format(
                self.table_name, "id", "version", "row_hash"
            )
        )
        select_sql = self.session.prepare(
            (
                "SELECT id, version, row_hash FROM {} WHERE  version=? AND id=?"
            ).format(
                self.table_name
            )
        )
        futures = []
        check_for_patch = [] #this list comprises rows with ids and values for checking whether its an update/insert
        rows_for_checking_patch = []
        start_time = datetime.utcnow()
        for df in chunks:
            rows_for_checking_patch = df.values.tolist()
            chunk_counter += 1
            df["row_hash"] = df.apply(
                self.hash_row
            )
            df["key"] = df["column_test_3"].apply(
                self.hash_string
            )
            keys = list(df["key"])
            row_hashes = list(df["row_hash"])
            start_time_de_params = datetime.utcnow()
            for i in range(chunksize):
                row_check = None
                params = (
                    str(keys[i]),
                    self.target_version, 
                    str(row_hashes[i])
                )
                check_for_patch_params = (
                    self.version,
                    str(keys[i])
                )
                check_for_patch.append(
                    (
                        select_sql,
                        check_for_patch_params
                    )
                )
                futures.append(
                    (
                        insert_sql,
                        params
                    )
                )
            self.log.info("Time for params: {}".format(datetime.utcnow() - start_time_de_params))
            if len(check_for_patch) >= patch_length_for_cql:
                start_time_de_update = datetime.utcnow()
                results = execute_concurrent(
                    self.session, check_for_patch, concurrency=concurrency_value, raise_on_first_error=False
                )
                self.log.info("Time for just the query: {}".format(datetime.utcnow() - start_time_de_update))
                row_counter_for_patch = 0
                for (success, result) in results:
                    if not result:
                        self.push_to_patch(
                            keys[row_counter_for_patch],
                            rows_for_checking_patch[row_counter_for_patch],
                            mode='insert'
                        )
                        row_counter_for_patch += 1
                        continue
                    if not success:
                        # result will be an Exception
                        self.log.error("Error has occurred in insert cql")
                        self.handle_error(result)
                    id_to_be_compared = result[0]["id"]
                    row_hash_to_be_compared = result[0]["row_hash"]
                    if (row_hash_to_be_compared != row_hashes[row_counter_for_patch]):
                        self.push_to_patch(
                            id_to_be_compared,
                            rows_for_checking_patch[row_counter_for_patch]["row"],
                            mode='update'
                        )
                    row_counter_for_patch += 1
                del check_for_patch[:]
                del rows_for_checking_patch[:]
                row_counter_for_patch = 0
                self.log.info("Time for check patch: {}".format(
                    datetime.utcnow() - start_time_de_update
                ))

            if (len(futures) >= patch_length_for_cql):
                start_time_de_insert = datetime.utcnow()
                results = execute_concurrent(
                    self.session, futures, concurrency=concurrency_value, raise_on_first_error=False
                )
                for (success, result) in results:
                    if not success:
                        # result will be an Exception
                        self.log.error("Error has occurred in insert cql")
                        self.handle_error(result)
                del futures[:]
                self.log.info("Time for insert patch: {}".format(
                    datetime.utcnow() - start_time_de_insert
                    ))
            self.log.info(chunk_counter)
            # self.log.info("This chunk got over in {}".format(datetime.utcnow() - start_time))

        if len(check_for_patch) > 0:
            results = execute_concurrent(
                self.session, check_for_patch, concurrency=concurrency_value, raise_on_first_error=False
            )
            row_counter_for_patch = 0
            for (success, result) in results:
                if not result:
                    self.push_to_patch(
                        rows_for_checking_patch[row_counter_for_patch]["id"],
                        rows_for_checking_patch[row_counter_for_patch]["row"],
                        mode='insert'
                    )
                    row_counter_for_patch += 1
                    continue
                if not success:
                    # result will be an Exception
                    self.log.error("Error has occurred in insert cql")
                    self.handle_error(result)
                id_to_be_compared = result[0]["id"]
                row_hash_to_be_compared = result[0]["row_hash"]
                if (row_hash_to_be_compared != rows_for_checking_patch[row_counter_for_patch]["row_hash"]):
                    self.push_to_patch(
                        id_to_be_compared,
                        rows_for_checking_patch[row_counter_for_patch]["row"],
                        mode='update'
                    )
                    row_counter_for_patch += 1
            del check_for_patch[:]
            del rows_for_checking_patch[:]

        if len(futures) > 0:   # in case the last dataframe has #rows < 10k.
            results = execute_concurrent(
                self.session, futures, concurrency=concurrency_value, raise_on_first_error=False
            )
            for (success, result) in results:
                if not success:
                    self.handle_error(result)
            del futures[:]
            self.log.info(chunk_counter)

        # Check the delete patch
        if self.generate_diff is True and self.mode is 'replace' and self.version is not 0:
            self.log.info("We got to find the delete patch!")
            start_time = datetime.utcnow()
            current_version_query = "SELECT id, row, row_hash FROM {} WHERE version={}".format(
                self.table_name, self.version
            )
            current_version_rows = self.session.execute(
                current_version_query
            )
            for current_version_row in current_version_rows:
                row_check_query = "SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE {}={} AND {}='{}' ".format(
                    "id", self.table_name, "version", self.target_version, "id", current_version_row.id
                )
                row_check = self.session.execute(row_check_query).one()
                if row_check is not None:  # row exists in both version.
                    continue
                self.push_to_patch(
                    current_version_row.id,
                    current_version_row.id,
                    mode="delete"
                )
        print("Complete insert's duration is: {}".format(
            datetime.utcnow() - start_time)
        )
        # Calling last_patch for all remaining diffs
        modes = [
            'update',
            'insert',
            'delete'
        ]
        for mode in modes:
            json_patch_file = os.path.join(
                self.working_dir,
                "version_{}_{}.json".format(
                    self.target_version, mode
                )
            )
            if mode == 'update':
                self.push_to_update_patch(
                    json_patch_file,
                    last_patch=True
                )
            if mode == 'insert':
                self.push_to_insert_patch(
                    json_patch_file,
                    last_patch=True
                )
            if mode == 'delete':
                self.push_to_delete_patch(
                    json_patch_file,
                    last_patch=True
                )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example1 = PythonCassandraExample(
        file_to_be_versioned="hundred_million_eleven_columns.csv"
    )
    example1.createsession()
    example1.setlogger()
    example1.createkeyspace('sat_athena_one')
    example1.create_table_and_set_version('five_hundred_rows')
    example1.clone_version()
    example1.insert_data(generate_diff=True)
```

I have a csv file of 100M rows and 11 cols. The script used to generate such a file is:

```
import csv
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd

file_name = "hundred_million_eleven_columns.csv"
rows_list = []
chunk_counter = 1
headers = [
    "column_test_1",
    "column_test_2",
    "column_test_3",
    "column_test_4",
    "column_test_5",
    "column_test_6",
    "column_test_7",
    "column_test_8",
    "column_test_9",
    "column_test_10",
    "column_test_11",
]

file_exists = os.path.isfile(file_name)
with open(file_name, 'a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=headers)
    if not file_exists:
        writer.writeheader()  # file doesn't exist yet, write a header

for i in range(100000000):
    dict1 = [
        i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5, i+6, i+7, i+8, i+9, i+10
    ]
    # get input row in dictionary format
    # key = col_name
    rows_list.append(dict1)
    if len(rows_list) == 100000:
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
        df.to_csv(file_name,
                  mode='a', index=False, header=False)
        del rows_list[:]
        del df
        print(chunk_counter)
        chunk_counter += 1
if len(rows_list) > 0:
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
    df.to_csv(file_name, mode='a', index=False, header=False)
    del rows_list[:]
    del df
    print(chunk_counter)
    chunk_counter += 1
```

My cassandra's yaml file is [here](https://pastebin.com/NFd6K7bg)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your code can even generate that much at 50k. If you remove the execute's, can you even read the CSV and generate the sha that fast? A C* instance on that sized host with SSDs should be able to do 50k writes/sec but theres a lot going on outside of the C* writes that are likely part of the issue.

If your concurrent reads/writes are above 128 you are going to have some serious issues. On a system that can handle it 64 even is enough be able to go past 200k writes a sec. You are actually going to make things much worse with that high of a setting. There is no IO involved in that so as the documentation states, 8x your core count is a good value. I would even recommend lowering the concurrency your pushing from 10k to like 1024 or even lower. You can play with different settings to see how it impacts things.

Make sure python was compiled with cython on your install as its going to be dominated on the serialization otherwise. Speaking of the python driver is the slowest so keep that in mind.

Your blocking on the sha can be a majority of the time. Without perf tracing - just try it with a fixed value to see the difference.

"My machine" -- is this a single node cluster? If your throwing availability out the window might as well disable durable_writes on the keyspace to speed up the writes a bit. Missing heap settings but make sure you have a minimum of 8gb, even if this is a pretty small host cassandra needs memory. If not reading consider disabling the keycache and maybe disabling compactions while the job is running and then enable afterwards.

Comment: Yes its a single machine cluster. Eventually, it"le a multi cluster setup when in prod.

Comment: I have updated the code and followed your instructions. The `check_for_patch` query which is a select statement takes 22 seconds, just the query and not iterating over the results. How can I reduce my select query?

Comment: To improve read performance add keycache back in... missed that. How many queries is that?

Comment: Concurrent read set to 1k or 64 yields the same result: 100,000 rows/22 seconds.

Comment: Also, where should I add keycache? https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSetCaching.html

Comment: 13ms a read isnt _that_ terrible but definitely can be better (reads are going to be worse than writes). If you haven't changed the keycache settings its on. Could try switching to LeveledCompactionStrategy (better reads, especially with overwrites) - make sure you wait until compactions are done (`nodetool compactionstats`) unless you can truncate before your test. Can check gc logs to make sure gcs are not long.

Comment: How can I create a table with keycache? I have already changed the settings in the yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Comment recomends 8 * number of cores.

> On the other hand, since writes are almost never IO bound, the ideal
>   number of "concurrent_writes" is dependent on the number of cores in
>   your system; (8 * number_of_cores) is a good rule of thumb.

64 is proper in 8core machine.

- concurrent_reads: 64
- concurrent_writes: 64
- concurrent_counter_writes: 64

This limits are may recommended because there are many other io operations except normal IO. ex) writting commit log, caching, compaction, replication, view (if exist)

Some rules of thumb

- disk_optimization_strategy: ssd // If your disk is hdd, chage value to spinning
- use dedicated commit log disk. ssd recommended.
- more disks = better performance