# How do I set caching for reading rows fast in Cassandra using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cql

My code for creating table is:

```
c_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (id varchar, version int, row_hash varchar, PRIMARY KEY((version), id)) WITH caching ('keys' : 'NONE')".format(
            self.table_name
        )
```

My aim is to decreasing read(select query) time which is currently 100k rows / 20 secs. Hence, I want to have a caching system as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317785/10060068). However, I could only find one syntax of doing so and it is yielding errors.
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getting_started.py", line 420, in <module>
    example1.create_table_and_set_version('five_hundred_rows')
  File "getting_started.py", line 116, in create_table_and_set_version
    self.session.execute(c_sql)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2171, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 4062, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:130 no viable alternative at input '(' (...version), id)) WITH [caching] (...)">
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct query to run is

```
create table if not EXISTS my_ks.my_table ( id varchar, version int, row_hash varchar , primary KEY ((version),id)) WITH caching = {'keys': 'NONE'}
```

I recommend to try the query first in cqlsh in order to detect some mismatches, like in this case. The correct syntax for caching is

```
...WITH caching = {'keys': 'NONE'}
```